# nonce in custom form is not verifying

Tags: forms

I have a shortcode which calls an html form:

```
function add_signup_form () {
    require_once ( "apps/registration_form.php");
    return signup_form();
}
add_shortcode( 'add_signup_form', 'add_signup_form' );
```

The form loads on the WordPress page just fine. But when the form is submitted the nonce is not validating.

```
function signup_form() {     
    $form = '<form action="'.plugins_url().'/sunday-signup/apps/save_registration.php" method="post" id="setting">
                 ' . wp_nonce_field( "register","registration_nonce" ). '  
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit_registration" value="Save Reservation" class="button">
    </form>';
    
    return $form;
}
```

in the processing .php I'm able to `print_r($_POST)` and see the value of the nonce and other fields, but my condition won't satisfy.:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit_registration']) ) {

    if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['registration_nonce'], 'register' ) ) {
```

I've done this many times, but never using a shortcode. Is that the issue?

**Update:**

As it turns out, it had nothing to do with nounces, but all WordPress functions were "undefined." Once I added the following to the top of my script, everything worked.

```
require_once $_POST['root_dir'].'/wp-load.php';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this answers the question, but you should call [`wp_nonce_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/) with the fourth parameter (`$echo`) set to `false`:

```php
// You are concatenating or not directly echoing the output, so:
. wp_nonce_field( 'register', 'registration_nonce', true, false ) .
```

And I said "not sure" because you said the posted data (`$_POST`) did include the nonce field, so check the form source (HTML) and make sure the nonce field is not being used twice or more, e.g.

```html
<!-- 'register' action: wp_nonce_field( 'register', 'registration_nonce', true, false ) -->
<input ... name="registration_nonce" value="nonce" />
...
<!-- A different action: wp_nonce_field( 'foo-bar', 'registration_nonce', true, false ) -->
<input ... name="registration_nonce" value="nonce2" />
```

So in that case, assuming the valid action is `register`, then `wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['registration_nonce'], 'register' )` is going to fail because the second nonce field above (for the `foo-bar` action) overrides the first one (for the `register` action).

### Update

So you confirmed the duplicate nonce field issue indeed occurred, but now after you fixed that issue, you're getting the error `500` on your form processing page, which I'm assuming is your custom `sunday-signup/apps/save_registration.php` file?

If so, then you should actually not submit to a static PHP file. Instead, use one of the early (or on-page-load) hooks in WordPress like `template_redirect` to process the form submission.

```php
// Example using the template_redirect hook:
add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit_registration'], $_POST['registration_nonce'] ) ) {
        if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['registration_nonce'], 'register' ) ) {
            // your code here
            // ...

            // then redirect back, maybe..
            wp_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
            exit;
        } else {
            echo 'test error';
            exit;
        }
    }
} );
```

The above example should work, but the actual code which processes the form submission is all *up to you*. Just make sure you call `wp_verify_nonce()` and other WordPress functions in the right place.

Comment: You pointed out something that I checked. The hidden fields are indeed appearing twice! The first set is above the form tag. I am baffled as to how this could be happening, but this must be the problem. Not sure how to debug this, or if it's a WordPress characteristic in this sort of situation.

Comment: $echo set to false, and code doesn't duplicate. But now the $_POST array is completely empty and getting the white screen of death. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: $echo set to false, and code doesn't duplicate. `print-r($_POST)` before the verify line shows ALL name/values, but notw getting 500 errors 'Call to undefined functions (wp_verify_nonce and sanitize...), hence the white screen.

Comment: The "Update" part might help. Let me know.

Comment: after a lot of research, I found that I "simply" had to `require_once $_POST['root_dir'].'/wp-load.php';` at the top of my script. Turns out, no WordPress function were "defined".

Comment: Alright then if you'd rather use the static file than using hook (to process the form submission), but the point as I said in the answer is, make sure the WordPress functions are already loaded by the time that you call the functions. My original answer also helped you, right?

Comment: It did. The double declaration was the first issue wth the nonce. The second was the necessity of loading the WordPress functions. Being relatively new to WordPress, and with a long history of Perl, I'm still trying get my head around best practices in WordPress. I'll explore this idea of not calling a static file as I am so used to doing. Any other resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Using a static file is not exactly an evil. It works, after all, when done properly. But WordPress is all about using hooks to make things go, and plugins also rely upon hooks and conditional tags like [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) to run certain actions, so if you use the static file, then the conditional tags would likely fail and may affect the efficiency of the plugins on your site, e.g. certain important actions are missed (because they run only on certain Pages - posts of the `page` type, and `is_page()` on static file returns a `false`).